# Is light penetration through water affected by water pressure?

Tags: optics, visible-light, pressure, water

Does water pressure affect propagation of light through water?

Comment: This seems to be a rather broad question. Please specify, what exactly you are interested in. Is it the propagation speed, attenuation, or something else?

Comment: permeability, so mostly distance then, water propagation decreases with depth, pressure also increases with depth, was wondering if there is some correlation there. for example, at pressure 1 bar compared to pressure 200 bar (equivalent to 200 meters depth), does the distance light can propagate differ significantly?

Comment: why the question said "light penetration", as in "permeability through water". stackexchange required I also add a bit of text which may be what made it less precise

Comment: Educated guess:  If the density barely changes, absorption of light will barely change.  However, the dielectric properties of water, which govern propagation at radio (vice optical) frequencies, are quite sensitive to temperature.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://water.lsbu.ac.uk/water/water_density.html#:%7E:text=The%20density%20of%20liquid%20water,and%20decreases%20with%20increasing%20temperature.), the density of water is impacted by both its pressure and temperature. According to [this](https://hal.science/hal-00753531/document#:%7E:text=The%20refractive%20index%20and%20polarizability,in%20an%20interferometer%20optical%20arrangement.), the index of refraction has a predictable and measurable change up to 250 MPa (nearly 2500 atmospheres).

The other answers have noted implicitly that water is often well approximated as an incompressible fluid, and the changes in both density and refractive index are quite modest, so ... the answer is that it depends on what you're really asking. The deepest place on Earth that we know of (there could be a cave system that goes deeper somewhere), the Mariana Trench, has a pressure of just under 110 MPa and a temperature of about 275K which puts it in the "boring" region of the water phase diagram where not much changes in any direction. Certainly, you can measure a change in the index of refraction, but the density plays a bigger role, and it's just not that much different from the surface. All of that said, the ocean has impurities which make it more dense and those will have a bigger effect than the pressure, and the turbidity will have a much larger effect than that.

If you're asking for a friend (Europa, Ganymede and Callisto), then the answer is yeah, that's easily an important and measurable quantity at the suspected depths of those oceans, but we don't know too much about their composition, turbidity or actual depths.

Answer (score 1):

> Does water pressure affect propagation of light through water?

The short answer is no, not really. At commonly achievable pressures, the effect will be negligible.

At a macroscopic level, the effect of a material (e.g., water) on light propagation is almost entirely described by the material's dielectric function. For example, the speed of light in the material is determined by the index of refraction which is the real part of the dielectric function. For example, the absorption of light is determined by the coefficient of absorption which is the imaginary part of the inverse dielectric function.

The absorption is also proportional to the density, but because water is already almost as compressed as it can be, and because commonly achievable pressures can't really compress water much more than it already is, pressure will not noticeably affect the propagation of light (for the most part).

Answer (score 0):

no, the weight may be greater but the space of the water molecules are still the same as if it was at the surface.